Thymeleaf Issue: Unable to Retrieve Correct ID Values
The issue arises when attempting to pass the dynamic goodsId from HTML to a JavaScript function. Instead of the expected numeric value, the goodsId is being treated as a string literal (e.g., ${row.goodsId}) and not being resolved correctly in the oninput event handler. This leads to errors when trying to access related elements in the calc function, resulting in null references and causing the script to fail. The challenge lies in ensuring that the correct value is parsed and passed into the JavaScript function during runtime.
html
<input type="hidden" name="${row.goodsId}" th:value="${row.goodsId}"/>
<input name="quantity_${row.goodsId}" type="number" th:value="${row.quantity}" min="0"
       aria-label="數量" th:attr="oninput='calc(this.previousElementSibling.value, this)'"/>

JavaScript Function
function calc(goodsId, quantity) {
console.log("Calculating subtotal for goodsId: " + goodsId + " with quantity: " + quantity.value);
var priceElement = document.getElementById("price_" + goodsId);

if (priceElement) {
    var price = parseFloat(priceElement.textContent) || 0;
    var qtyValue = parseInt(quantity.value) || 0;
    var subtotal = price * qtyValue;

    var subtotalElement = document.getElementById("subtotal_" + goodsId);
    if (subtotalElement) {
        subtotalElement.textContent = subtotal.toFixed(2);
    } else {
        console.error("Subtotal element not found for goodsId: " + goodsId);
    }
}

}
Error Reference
Subtotal for goodsId: ${row.goodsId} = 6798

The controller successfully adds messages to the cart and can return the current cart in the session:
AddGoodsRequest(goodsId=1, goodsName=Dell Achievement 3470 High-Performance Business Desktop Computer, goodsPrice=3399.0, quantity=1), 
AddGoodsRequest(goodsId=4, goodsName=Dell Vostro 3668-R2938, goodsPrice=6699.0, quantity=1)

HTML structur
<form action="@{/goods/add}" method="post">
    <script>
        function calc(goodsId, quantity) {
            console.log("Calculating subtotal for goodsId: " + goodsId + " with quantity: " + quantity.value);
            var priceElement = document.getElementById("price_" + goodsId);
            console.log("Price for goodsId: " + goodsId + " = " + priceElement.textContent);
            if (priceElement) {
                var price = parseFloat(priceElement.textContent) || 0;
                var qtyValue = parseInt(quantity.value) || 0;
                var subtotal = price * qtyValue;

                var subtotalElement = document.getElementById("subtotal_" + goodsId);
                if (subtotalElement) {
                    subtotalElement.textContent = subtotal.toFixed(2);
                } else {
                    console.error("Subtotal element not found for goodsId: " + goodsId);
                }
                console.log("Subtotal for goodsId: " + goodsId + " = " + subtotal);

                var total = 0;
                var subtotalElements = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='subtotal_']");
                subtotalElements.forEach(function (subtotalElement) {
                    total += parseFloat(subtotalElement.textContent) || 0;
                });

                document.getElementById("total").textContent = total.toFixed(2);
            }
        }

        window.onload = function () {

        };
    </script>

    <table className="threeboder">
        <thead>
        <tr bgcolor="#A5D3FF">
            <th align="center" className="theader">商品名稱</th>
            <th width="8%" align="center" className="theader">數量</th>
            <th width="15%" align="center" className="theader">單價</th>
            <th width="15%" align="center" className="theader">小計</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <th:block th:each="row : ${cartrow}">
            <tr>
                <td align="left" className="trow">
                    <span th:text="${row.goodsName}">123</span>
                </td>
                <td align="center" className="trow">
                    <input type="hidden" name="${row.goodsId}" th:value="${row.goodsId}"/>
                    <input name="quantity_${row.goodsId}" type="number" th:value="${row.quantity}" min="0"
                           aria-label="數量" th:attr="oninput='calc(&quot;${row.goodsId}&quot;, this)'"/>
                </td>
                <td align="center" className="trow">$<span id="price_${row.goodsId}" th:text="${row.goodsPrice}"></span>
                </td>
                <td align="center" className="trow">
                    $<span id="subtotal_${row.goodsId}"
                           th:text="${row.goodsPrice != null && row.quantity != null ? (row.goodsPrice * row.quantity) : 0}"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <td colSpan="4" style="height: 2px; background-color: #5A96D6;"></td> <!-- 分隔 -->
        </th:block>
        <tr>
            <td colSpan="3" align="right">合計：$<span id="total">0.00</span></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div align="center">
        <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(cart)}">
            <input type="image" th:src="@{/images/submit_order.jpg}" border="0" alt="提交訂單"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="sub_ord"/>
</form>

Current Behavior

The subtotal only updates for the first item when the quantity changes.

The item IDs cannot be retrieved correctly in the JavaScript function.


